# Smartgit install error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, smartgit

I am installing smartgit on Ubuntu 16.04

`.../smartgit_7.1.3-0~eugenesan~xenial1_all.deb ..`

Apparently, smartgit installs OK, but when I start it:

```
J:~$ smartgit
intx MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1073741823 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The Java sems to be OK, too

```
    J:~$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode)
J:~$
```

Any idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: off-topic or not, this was what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

In `bin/smartgit.sh` change following line from:

```
_MISC_OPTS="-Xverify:none -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false"
```

to

```
_MISC_OPTS="-Xverify:none -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=1000000 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false"
```

This fix is already present in [SmartGit 7.2 Preview](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/preview).

Comment: I do not find a line you mentioned. I do have line _MISC_OPTS="-Xverify:none -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false". Adding the line you suggested has no effect, Thanks anyhow. I'll try the preview.

Comment: So there is no `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=` present in  your `smartgit.sh`?

Comment: Finally, I found the reason: the install installed smartgit in my home, but the soft link continued pointing to /usr/share... After copying the preview you mentioned to /usr/share, I receive message Unsupported system classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@10ee7cb

Comment: It seems like java-9 is not yet supported with smartgit, so install java-8 and do: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` then choose the java-8 option and copy the path that appears in that option.

 After that `sudo nano /etc/environment` and paste at the end of the file `JAVA_HOME="here/goes/the/copied/path"` save that and reload the file `source /etc/environment` and that is it.

If you want to check if you configured well the JAVA_HOME just enter in console: `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it should returns the path that you pasted there.